# Visual style set on BS_CHECKBOX button overrides NM_CUSTOMDRAW

Tags: c++, winapi

I am looking to create a checkbox in the C++ WinAPI with a custom bitmap resource as the actual check box.

Unfortunately, when I create a `WM_NOTIFY`-compatible checkbox (That actually deals with `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` in a meaningful way), it seems to work just fine except for one thing: The checkbox seems to fade when changing states. This has to do with the visual style, it seems, so I simply unset the visual style with `SetWindowTheme(chkLogging, _T(" "), _T(" "));`.

```
HWND chkLogging = CreateWindowEx(
    NULL,
    _T("button"),
    _T("Export to log file"),
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX | BS_NOTIFY,
    300, 100, 100, 20,
hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EXPORTLOG, NULL, NULL);
CheckDlgButton(hWnd, IDC_EXPORTLOG, BST_CHECKED);
SetWindowTheme(chkLogging, _T(" "), _T(" "));
```

Unfortunately, setting the theme for that `HWND` will override the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` rendering. I have tested this by removing the `SetWindowTheme` line and trying with the default theme, and the checkbox `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` worked like a charm.

This typically wouldn't be an issue, but it actually works as seemingly intended for normal buttons.

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated :)